# How can I add current time to an existing date object?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have a date object like so:

> 2016-06-30 00:00:00

What I need is take the current time, let's say

> 01.07.2016 14:56

Add to the first date object so it would look like this:

> 2016-06-30 14:56:00

I understand that one can add time by adding to a strtotime object and one can also use the add function of datetime. But what I have a hard time is figuring out how to extract the time part and then add it to the first datetime object.

Is there a simple way for it or am I going to have to kind of hack it?

Thank you

Comment: what if the first date has a time close to midnight? `2016-06-30 23:00:00`. After adding this time `14:56` the resulting date should not be `2016-06-30`

Comment: The first date is always midnight. I probably should have cleared that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$d1 = '01.07.2016 14:56';
$dt = new DateTime($d1);
$date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');
$time = $dt->format('H:i:s');

$d2 ='2016-06-30 00:00:00';
$dt2 = new DateTime($d2);
$date2 = $dt2->format('Y-m-d');

$final_date=$date2.' '.$time;
echo $final_date ;
```

Result== 2016-06-30 14:56:00

Answer (score 1):

This explains how you can do it: [Set Time](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settime.php)
Just call:

```
date_time_set($date, 14, 56, 00); // $date is your date object
```

Since the date object is always midnight the value of the time is zero and can therefor be overwritten without loosing any information. If you can have more then 24 Hours to add there are other better ways. But for this we would need more information.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], if you don't want to create a new object
get the "datediff()" and then use modify to add that to existing object.

When you change the time at almost midnight and potentially you should change the date also. In this scenario if you use "modify()" and add TimeInterval to it. system will take care of the Date change also.

if you are not worried about date changes. then setTime() is always there for us.